# Most efficient way to call a PHP endpoint using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Using jQuery to call an endpoint and populate the data on the frontend is a common task. After searching and using multiple solutions the below is my current blueprint for any ajax calls.

How can I improve the following to be faster and more efficient? I realize doing it in pure javascript will be faster but at this point I assume jQuery will be present.

Frontend - Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function callEndpoint( call_url, payload ){
        return $.ajax({
            url: call_url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: payload
        });
    }
    $( '.get-endpoint' ).click( function() {
        sSelected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( sSelected );
        oRequest = callEndpoint( '/play/endpoint2.php', { 'type': sSelected } );
        oRequest.done(function( sJson ) {
            aData = JSON.parse( sJson );
            $( '.from-endpoint' ).text( aData.text );
        });
    });
});
```

Frontend - Html:

```
<body>
    <button class="get-endpoint">Games</button>
    <button class="get-endpoint">Books</button>
    <button class="get-endpoint">Comics</button>
    <div class="from-endpoint">Coming soon...</div>
</body>
```

Backend - PHP:

```
$aReturn[ 'text' ] = '';
if( !empty( $_GET ) )
{
    if( $_GET[ 'type' ] == 'Games' )
    {
        $aReturn[ 'text' ] = 'Text for games';
    }
    else if( $_GET[ 'type' ] == 'Books' )
    {
        $aReturn[ 'text' ] = 'Text for books';
    }
    else if( $_GET[ 'type' ] == 'Comics' )
    {
        $aReturn[ 'text' ] = 'Text for comics';
    }
}
$sJson = json_encode( $aReturn, 1 );
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo $sJson;
```

Comment: cache parameter in jQuery ajax is true by default - but you might wanna be sure that it is true if the content isn't changing often.

Comment: Have you measured it and found it to be slow? The bottleneck in your code would surely be the request itself, which you cannot do much about.

Comment: Please check the PHP documentation for the [`header` function](http://php.net/header). You're not using it the right way.

Comment: Vladimir, could you please elaborate on why the need is there for a more efficient way? The above solution is kind of standard in jQuery. The below solution about using getJSON is kind of valid, since you don't have to do JSON.parse anymore. That is added by the overload function. Making your code cleaner. I am not sure at the moment what kind of answer you are looking for. A refactor of your code?

Comment: I'm looking for ideas/suggestions that are often overlooked when it comes to getting a better parse time/attaining the most efficient performance possible. The getJSON I did not like as it still uses ajax to route through adding another function call.

Comment: I don't think there is much to improve here in terms of performance. Your code performance at this moment depends mostly on network latency between browser and remote point (where AJAX call is sent). Client-side event is triggered by click (cannot happen "faster"), server-side event is processed by a static set of "if" conditions. If you are not going to add 100 other AJAX URLs and request types – you probably shouldn't waste your time doing premature optimisations.

Comment: 1. the pure javascript code would be faster, still, using jQuery to do the ajax won't slow it down much; 2. it seems meaningless to --- so called ---pefect the "performance", since JS code can be executed quickly enough, and the limiting condition here is network, not js code or "jQuery code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this code can be more efficient in jQuery.
But you have some options left to give a more efficient feeling :

- You can use pagination to get a portion of your data each time. The
  less data to load, the quicker it get. And your application will be
  more responsive to the user's actions. This solution is a trick for
  the user, because it will take in reality more time than before to load all the data.
- You can keep previous loaded data so when you click back on a button,
  it won't load again the data. But, this can only be used if the data 
  won't change much between each click. The first time you will click
  on a button, it will take the same time as before, but the next time,
  it will be immediat.

Be aware that the more HTML code you load, the more it will take time to initiate JavaScript behavior on it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your categories won't change often.  You can save some bandwidth by using JavaScript localstorage or cookies to cache data.  If you plan on connecting to a mysql database at somepoint you can use StoredProcedures which are variablized precompiled statements.

Comment: This is just a sandbox file not meant to go anywhere except limit the code for this example only. Obviously in production examples the listener will be attached to different events and the backend route will be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are anyways going to use JSON and jQuery, I would suggest that you should check out the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method of jQuery. I feel that it would reduce some lines of code, though I am not sure if it would help it become more efficient.
Anyways getJSON is just a shorthand of AJAX and I thought I should suggest this.

Comment: Disagreed. .getjson() calls .ajax(), so it will add to the overhead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Even I was not aware in deep about this. But looking into it cleared it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good approach for AJAX data transport browser->server->browser. Hope it suites your needs.

jQuery

```
$( function () {

    function fetch( data ) {

        var encoding = data.encoding,
            url = data.url,
            params = data.params,
            type = ( data.type ) ? : 'GET',
            cache = ( data.cache ) ? : 'false',
            async = ( data.async ) ? : 'true';

        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: async,
            cache: cache,
            data: params,
            dataType: encoding,
            type: type
        });
    }

    var options = {
            url: 'controller.php',
            params: {
                param_one: value_one,
                param_two: value_two,
                param_n: value_n
            },
            encoding: 'json'
        };

    // Get the JSON feed from the server
    $.when( fetch( options ) ).then( function ( response ) {

        // Is there anything in the pool?
        if ( response ) {

            // Store the response and use it in your code
            var data = response.data;

            console.log( data.responseOne );
            console.log( data.responseTwo );
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Controller

```
// Set header to application/json
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );

// Create the DB connection object
$dbc = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

// Initialize parameters array
$params = array();

// Store the query variables in an array
$query_type = ( $_GET ) ? : $_POST;

// Run foreach and store the values in an array
foreach ( $query_type as $key => $value ) {
    $params[ $key ] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, $value );
}

// Now you can access passed parameters like $params['param_name']

// This would be the data obtained from DB or some server array processing, whatever
$response = array(
    'data' => array(
        'response_one' => 'some_value',
        'response_two' => 'another_value'
     )
);

// Encode the result
echo json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: Yes, it basically returns the conditional. For instance, if your conditional is `isset([$_GET['value']])`, `$query_type` value will be `true` or `false`, depending on `$_GET['value']` being passed or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use pure javascript, you can improve your jQuery code with better [selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/)

For example, you can add an `id` in `<div class="from-endpoint">`

You can add tag in selector like this:

```
$('button.get-endpoint')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can drop your getEndpoint method and just use the `$.get` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( '.get-endpoint' ).click( function() {
        sSelected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( sSelected );
        oRequest = $.get('/play/endpoint2.php', { 'type': sSelected });
        oRequest.done(function( sJson ) {
            aData = JSON.parse( sJson );
            $( '.from-endpoint' ).text( aData.text );
        });
    });
});
```

2. You can make your code lint compliant.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( '.get-endpoint' ).click( function() {
        var sSelected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( sSelected );
        oRequest = $.get('/play/endpoint2.php', { type: sSelected });
        oRequest.done(function( sJson ) {
            var aData = JSON.parse( sJson );
            $( '.from-endpoint' ).text( aData.text );
        });
    });
});
```

3. Use success instead of done & move the callback to it's own function

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( '.get-endpoint' ).click( function() {
        var sSelected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( sSelected );
        $.get(
            '/play/endpoint2.php',
            { type: sSelected },
            insertData
        );
    });
});

function insertData( sJson ) {
    var aData = JSON.parse( sJson );
    $( '.from-endpoint' ).text( aData.text );
}
```

4. Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` or `$.ajax`

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( '.get-endpoint' ).click( function() {
        var sSelected = $( this ).text();
        console.log( sSelected );
        $.getJSON(
            '/play/endpoint2.php',
            { type: sSelected },
            insertData
        );
    });
});

function insertData( data ) {
    $( '.from-endpoint' ).text( data.text );
}
```

Comment: Sure, but your method uses it as well, so you're just duplicating code already present in the jQuery library. On top of that. Nested functions won't add that much overhead.

It's better to use cleaner, more battle tested methods present within a library than to reinvent the wheel and write your own methods, which are more error-prone.